# What is the Difference between two code snippets?

Tags: c, recursion

```
int factorial(int n) { 
    return ( n==0 ? 1 : factorial(n-1)*n ) ; 
}
```

vs.

```
int factorial(int n) { 
    return ( n==0 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1) ) ;
}
```

I want to know which one is prefered to use. 
is there any diference between them.
is there a situation that we must consider in order of function calls or variable calculations to achive better run time.

Comment: I'd say they're exactly the same. Why don't you bench them?

Comment: Is there any functional difference?

Comment: The code isn't the same, but I don't think that one is more time-efficient than the other.

Comment: So, it seems like you are too lazy to actually benchmark this yourself? [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Probably the most "time efficient" would be using a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: i want to know which is better in logical analysis cashmstr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. C doesn't specify the order of execution of the `*` operands, so `a * b` and `b * a` are effectively equivalent, for any expressions `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is the order it is needed to evaluate both `n` and `f(n-1)`, and as computing one of these expressions is not related to evaluating the other, time is the same.